# Simple proof of mulitnomial covariance?

Tags: probability-theory

Choose $m$ independent trials, each of which results in any of $r$ possible outcomes with probabilities $p_1, p_2, ......, p_r$ where $\sum_{i=1}^r {P_i} = 1$.

Let $N_i$ denote the number of trials that result in outcome $i = 1,...,r$.

Find the covariance between $N_i$ and $N_j$

Now I know that  $Cov(N_i,N_j) = -np_ip_j$ but what's a quick proof of that using basic laws of expected values and variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might as well let $N=1$. (Because the sum of two independent multinomial count vectors based on the same probability vectors and sample sizes $m$ and $n$ is again multinomial with sample size $m+n$, and the covariances of the sum of two independent vectors add.)  Then $\operatorname{Cov}(N_i,N_j)=E N_i N_i - EN_i EN_j$, where the counts $N_k$  are $0,1$ random variables, the indicators that the single pick was an $i$ or a $j$.  So $N_iN_j=0$ with probability 1, and $EN_i = p_i$ and $EN_j=p_j$, and the desired covariance is obtained.